# How do I pass 2 Parameters to a jQuery.Find function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass in 2 parameters to a jQuery.Find() function to get a piece of data. I currently have the following code

```
$(container).find('[name="cars",' + 'class="selected"]').val()
```

but its giving me an unrecognized expression error.

Is there a way I can combine the 2 parameters I have into one call?

Comment: `[name="cars"].selected`, `.selected[name="cars"]`, `[name="cars"][class="selected"]` ... take your pick.

Comment: It's not a matter of two bits of string. It's a matter of the resulting expression being invalid, no matter how many strings it's constructed out of.